# How can I get inside /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans from terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, netbeans, command-line, terminal

How can I get inside

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans
```

from the terminal?

Terminal can show up to:

```
kushals-MacBook-Pro:NetBeans kushalatreya$ ls NetBeans 8.2.app
```

but I cannot get inside *NetBeans 8.2.app* to view contents from Terminal. However I can right click and click `Show contents` from Finder.

I wanted to open Contents >> Resources >> NetBeans >> bin to change JRE to JDK platform. I can download JDK version from the browser, but wanted to know about the way through in Terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the space in the path. You need to add a backslash.

```
cd /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/
```

However the path autocompletion of the terminal does it for you.

As a site note: if you want to change the JDK, I recommend to set the value for netbeans_jdkhome in etc/netbeans.conf.